# how to upload image to wordpress using JSon api

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-json-api

I am very new to wordpress, trying to create post with featured image from a separate .Net application using JSon api. Please help with the info about how can I upload image from external source (using url) and mark as featured image using the api.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found the answer .. the answer is this plugin is not at all very flexible and customization is a tedious job to do with plugin  :) better to write your own plugin or use xml rpc..

Answer (score 1):

use XML rpc .. it can not be done with json api ..